# SQL-запрос

Tags: php, mysql

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO messTabl (UserName, PhoneNum, EMail, TextMess) VALUE ('"$userName"','"$mail"','"$phone"','"$message"')");

Не выполняется. Где ошибка?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке вы нам сообщите, или это задача повышенной сложности и мы должны сами догадаться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
VALUEs
```